# Linq mapping between models

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I have a data-model for Entity Framework in which some entities have a collection of attributes that can be used to add extra information. Some clients would like to map these attributes to 'real' properties of their own domain-model. An example data-model is:

```
public class DataEntity {  
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
public class DataAttribute {
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public String Value { get; set; }
}
public class DataStringAttribute : DataAttribute {
   public String Value { get; set; }
}
public class DataInt32Attribute : DataAttribute {
   public Int32 Value { get; set; }
}
```

And an example domain-model is:

```
public class DomainEntity {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }  
}
```

I can fairly easily map the entities between eachother, but I would like to be able to map Linq expressions between the two so that in the client, it would be `IQueryable<DomainEntity>`, but this is mapped to `IQueryable<DataEntity>` - for example:

```
myDomainEntities.Where(o => o.Age > 21)
```

could be mapped to:

```
myDataEntities.Where(o => o.Attributes.OfType<DataInt32Attribute>()
    .Any(o => o.Name = "Age" && o.Value > 21);
```

What would be the best way to do this - perhaps write a QueryProvider that walks the expression tree and translates it to one that uses the Data model - a Linq-to-Linq-to-EntityFramework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is atypical.  You might need to override the Linq-to-Entity provider and override its query-generation functionality.  You'll be walking the expression tree yourself and then dynamically converting that expression tree to a new tree that Linq-to-Entity can work with, then pass that tree to the original provider for query-generation.

In other words, you are hijacking Linq-to-Entity to support your custom format.  Hairy, but if you get it working, please write about it!  I'd be glad to learn how it works!

Also, you understand that your client will not get Intellisense support though, unless you write you custom plugin for VS also.  The code will also be flagged as syntax errors in VS (I am not sure whether it will compile).  That is because the class definitions really didn't change -- the entities didn't really have those properties.

Comment: I think the appoach - albeit being a lot of work - to create an intermediate query provider would work and would be compilable. Performance wise, it would prbably be not that great. I just wonder if there are any other options, and whether anyone has attempted this.

Comment: I don't think anybody has attempted this, at least not in wide knowledge.  However, do be careful about VS flagging these as errors -- you are rewriting thye expression tree to convert from error to correct, but VS doesn't know that.  It may flag them all as errors, and may refuse to compile.